# How to retry ajax on fail in react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I created the app with react js. In this app i'm having one post request. If this request has failed, I want to recall this request on error call back. How to implement with ajax? Please check the below code,

```
handleSubmit() {
    var resObj = {
        "TITLE":this.state.title,
        "NAME":this.state.name
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:url+"activity"+id,
        type:"PUT",
        data:JSON.stringify(resObj),
        dataType:'json',
        headers:{"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization":localStorage.getItem('token')},
        success:function(data, status){
        }.bind(this),
        error:function(xhr, status, err, data){
            if(xhr.status == 401 || xhr.status == 500 || xhr.status == 200) {
                $.ajax(this);
            }
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use $.ajax(this) in this way. $.ajax method requires an object as you did at the first call. The 'this' is bound to your react component by the way in your code. I think there are multiple solutions to solve your problem. A simple way is that you can just call the function again.

```
class RetryHandler{
    constructor(option){
      const defaultOptions = {
         // you can add default options here like maxRetry = 10, 
      };
      this.options = Object.assign({},defaultOptions,option);
      this.doSubmit();
    }

    doSubmit(){
      $.ajax({
        url:this.options.url,
        type:this.options.type,
        data:this.options.data,
        dataType:this.options.dataType,
        headers:this.options.headers,
        success:this.options.success,
        error:function(xhr, status, err, data){
            let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.push(this.doSubmit.bind(this));
            this.options.error.apply(this,args);
        }.bind(this)
      })

    }
 }

}



class App extends Component{

    handleSubmit() {

          new RetryHandler({
          url:"/mia",
          type:"POST",
          data:{name:"hello"},
          success:function(data, status){},
          error:function(xhr, status, err ,retry){
              setTimeout(function(){
                retry(); <-- on your error callback, you now have a retry function available, you just simply call this if you want to retry
              },1000);
          }
          });

    }

    render(){
      return <div onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Hello</div>
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm having so many handler action like this in my component. How to make this one to be global?

Comment: You can simply wrap it with a module. I make a very simple one for you.

Comment: I'm getting following error "TypeError: retry is not a function. (In 'retry()', 'retry' is undefined)"